# send an email on ssh failiure by keeo watching command

Tags: linux, email, ssh, sh

an email should trigger when ssh issue is resolved , so using watch with email trigger but is not working, and keep going in hang state. Why it is going in hang state

`` watch -n 600 if [ ! `ssh user@linux.example.com` ]; then mailx -s "ssh is ok now" ``

bash-4.1$ watch -n 600 if [ ! `ssh user@linux.example.com` ]; then mailx -s "ssh is ok now" example@example.com; fi

FIPS integrity verification test failed.
ssh: connect to host linux.example.com port 22: Connection refused
^C
(Interrupt -- one more to kill letter)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```sh
#/bin/bash
while true;do
  if nc -w 10 user@server.com 22 >/dev/null 2>&1;then
    echo "ssh is accessible"| mail -s "ssh is ok now" some@email.com
    break
  fi
  sleep 600
done
```

Assuming `sleep` wait is 600 seconds, and the connect `timeout` is 10 seconds, and port is: `22`